# How can I brute force an individual smb share?

Tags: metasploit, smb

I am trying to complete a CTF and am presented with a machine that has several SMB shares, as found using metasploit auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_enumshares.

```
- Windows XP Service Pack 3 (English)
- IPC$ - (I) Remote IPC
- Documents - (DS) 
- ADMIN$ - (DS) Remote Admin
- C$ - (DS) Default share
```

I am trying to access the shares marked with a `$` which are private and non accessible. I have tried using the `smb_login`, but as I am unable to specific an individual share from that list to target for a brute force scan, each time I try the scan finishes immediately with a message that the Documents share is anonymous, thus the brute force checking is useless (I understand why this is the case)

When I use `smbclient` to access the private shares, I am prompted for a password (which I don't have, hence the brute forcing). So my question is: Can I use smb_login or some other tool (preferably available on Linux) to brute force a particular share (eg  `ADMIN$`)?

Comment: If worst came to worst you could always script a brute force via smbclient.

Comment: Yeah I have considered that option @Hector in this particular case I was able to use rdp with Hydra as an alternative bruteforce of this machine but would be interesting to know still. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: hydra can do that, which is probably the answer to this question. So I'm voting to close as product recommendation.

Comment: Additionally, have you tried to sniff traffic off of that machine? Maybe you can grab an old SMB hash and john that or PTH? CTFs usually require little brute force.

Comment: I did have a look at Hydra but I couldn't seem to find the options to select a share but I will have another look. Just to clarify: Hydra has the ability to not only select a server to bruteforce using the SMB protocol, but also the specific share?

Answer (score -2):

The share access uses the SMB protocol, if you want to access these private shares you need to have the correct credentials.

I know that if your client is Windows , Anonymous credentials is passed if the current (yours) credentials does not has the permissions.

Linux by default is running Samba and there is one more product called [NQE](http://visualitynq.com/products/cifs-nqe) that is installed on a lot of machines, and i think these product are doing the same algorithm.

Summery:
Over SMB i don't think you can access these share, the SMB protocol protect this kind of "attacks"
Maybe you can try to access via NFS.

Comment: This is borderline not an answer but an uneducated, lengthy comment.